# SQL How to duplicate column with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(sm.quantity) AS col1,
  SUM(sm.quantity) AS col2,
FROM
  stock_batches
INNER JOIN stock_distributions AS sd
  ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id
INNER JOIN stock_movements AS sm
  ON sm.stock_distribution_id = sd.id
```

I want col2 to be a duplicate of col1 but with a condition; preferably make

```
col2 WHERE sd.transferrable = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
SUM(sm.quantity) AS col1,
SUM(case when sd.transferrable = true then sm.quantity else 0 end) as col2
FROM stock_batches
INNER JOIN stock_distributions AS sd
ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id
INNER JOIN stock_movements AS sm
ON sm.stock_distribution_id = sd.id;
```